# Can't display unicode on title bar in WIN32

Tags: c++, winapi, hwnd, createwindow

I have been trying to create a Window whose title bar could be in any language. But I am getting something like ▯*. I writing as escape characters as of now. I am attesting the entirity of the code.

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND Window, UINT Message, WPARAM WParam, LPARAM LParam) {
    switch(Message) {
        case WM_KEYDOWN: {
            switch(WParam) { 
                case 'O': { 
                    DestroyWindow(Window); 
                } break; 
            }
        } break;
        case WM_DESTROY: { 
            PostQuitMessage(0); 
        } break;
        default: { 
            return DefWindowProc(Window, Message, WParam,  LParam); 
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE Instance, HINSTANCE PrevInstance, PSTR CmdLine, int CmdShow) {

    WNDCLASSW WindowClass = {0};
    const wchar_t* ClassName = L"MyWindowClass";

    WindowClass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    WindowClass.hInstance = Instance;
    WindowClass.lpszClassName = ClassName;
    WindowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_CROSS);
    MessageBoxW(0, L"\u0906\u092a", L"\u0906\u092a", 0);

    if(!RegisterClassW(&WindowClass)) {
        MessageBoxW(0, L"RegisterClass failed", 0, 0);
        return GetLastError();
    }
    
    HWND Window = CreateWindowExW(0, ClassName, L"\u0906\u092a",
                                 WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_VISIBLE,
                                 CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                 CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                 0, 0, Instance, 0);
    
    if(!Window) {
        MessageBoxW(0, L"CreateWindowEx failed", 0, 0);
        return GetLastError();
    }
    
    int Running = 1;
    
    while(Running) {
        MSG Message;
        while(GetMessageW(&Message, NULL, 0, 0)) {
            if(Message.message == WM_QUIT) Running = 0;
            TranslateMessage(&Message);
            DispatchMessage(&Message);
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting the title bar to be something like 'आप'

Comment: Make sure you are using "Unicode Character Set" under "Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Advanced -> Character Set" or "    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>" in the .vcxproj file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable unicode when compiling using cl.exe from Visual Studio Build Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71040396/how-to-enable-unicode-when-compiling-using-cl-exe-from-visual-studio-build-tools)

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you are saying that this code (with escape characters) is working. Would it not have been better to also post the code that is not working, since that's the code you want help with?

Comment: @john It's not even working with the escape characters 

Comment: Works fine for me running on Windows 10 https://i.imgur.com/iYfrbUT.png https://i.imgur.com/Bv2DMVo.png The code is good, so it's more a Windows setup issue. Maybe you're missing fonts and/or languages.

Comment: Incorrect font seems like a possible explanation. Not all fonts can display all Unicode characters.

Comment: No repro for me on Windows 10. Pictures here: https://imgur.com/a/jaJvxUE

Comment: Since we cannot tell from the code provided, are you calling `DefWindowProcA` or `DefWindowProcW`?

Comment: Wierdly enough I am able to get Message box correct not the window 
https://postimg.cc/3WZbYY22 Working Message Box
https://postimg.cc/2VKGS6yL/82eda8b6 Not working Window Title
Should I test any other language?

Comment: @john It's not working with escape characters as well....What I meant was to test in escape character... Coz if it works I will make an converter easily.. but first this should run correctly... Please refer to image I posted... Is it due to a save format? Or compiler thing?

Comment: @AshutoshJha change `DefWindowProc` to `DefWindowProcW` to match all of the other W functions you are calling. Also, `if(Message.message == WM_QUIT)` in your message loop will never evaluate to true since `GetMessage()` returns 0,  breaking the loop, when `WM_QUIT` is received.

Comment: It also works fine for me on win11.Did you compile your application as Unicode? I suggest you could refer to the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417004/unicode-characters-in-window-caption

Answer (score 0):

You unintentionally mixed [ansi and wide character api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/working-with-strings#unicode-and-ansi-functions) probably due to incorrect project settings. The general advice is to explicitly use the wide character functions noted by a **W** at the end of the function name (e.g: `CreateWindowW`, `GetMessageW`) whenever possible. Avoid mixing ansi and wide character functions and avoid mixing the compatibility macros with explicit functions. Otherwise make **absolutly sure** that the `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` preprocessor directives are always defined as you would expect it.

*If the unicode definitions are enabled, wide character functions are used resulting in success. This is likely the reason many people say it worked on their machine. Your issue can be reproduced by using the ansi functions instead of macros.*

Microsoft in [Unicode and ANSI Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/working-with-strings#unicode-and-ansi-functions):

> New applications should always call the Unicode versions. Many world languages require Unicode. If you use ANSI strings, it will be impossible to localize your application. The ANSI versions are also less efficient, because the operating system must convert the ANSI strings to Unicode at run time.

Your code snippet still has two places where wide character functions are mandatory to support unicode titles. The `DefWindowProc` macro should become `DefWindowProcW` and the `DispatchMessage` macro should become `DispatchMessageW`. The exception is `LoadCursor` which can stay in the macro form due to the dependence on resource `IDC_CROSS`.

*FYI: The double while around your message loop is unnecessary because `GetMessageW` returns 0 when `PostQuitMessage(0)` is called, thus ending your message loop automatically.*